# How can I replace physical IoT devices during the application development?

Tags: microsoft-windows-iot

I am about to develop a .NET application for IoT devices.

In this moment I do not want to use physical devices, because I will run out of some precious time, but I do want to start building the application now.

Is there any way I can replace these devices to simulate my work flow, until I buy some real devices?

Comment: Hard to say without some information about the actual development environment being used, the target devices, and the target operating system. Visual Studio, for instance, offers several different software simulators of phones and other devices. I have done UWP development for Windows 10 IoT by testing on a PC with Windows 10 and then changing the target to a Raspberry Pi with Windows 10 IoT. The display of the Raspberry Pi was similar size to that of the Windows 10 development PC.

Answer (score 3):

No.

There's no emulator for a bunch of electronics that sit on a bench. Welcome to the trying world of embedded software development.

You could write your code so that you 'mock' some of the inputs, but unfortunately there is little choice other than plugging it in and switching it on. If you're doing Windows 10 IoT Core, with a UWP UI, you can build a lot of the UI to run on a PC, but it won't take you very far.

Comment: This is imprecise - if the system is *known* you can mock it with as high fidelity as you know it, outputs as well as inputs.  The problem with the question is that it doesn't *specify* the system.  It's almost as if the asker wants to "do IoT" without the bother of thinking about those pesky devices - which isn't IoT implementational at all, but at most an academic paper about networks.

Comment: The simulation depends ENTIRELY on the protocols that your devices use to interact with the world. For example in the world of MQTT, Google "MQTT Simulator" for examples of existing solutions.

Comment: I'm developing against a mock gateway that can simulate a range of sensors. As Chris says, the protocol is known so it's quite feasible to emulate the physical network of devices, and quite advantageous given I can mock a wider range of sensors and behaviour over a shorter period of time.